# $P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha$) inconsistency

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Here are two seemingly correct ways to compute $$P(\min(X, Y) \leq \alpha)$$

Approach 1: Observe that $\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha \iff$ at least one of $X \leq \alpha$ and $Y \leq \alpha$ is true. Then $$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha) = P(\{X \leq \alpha\} \bigcup \{Y \leq \alpha\}) = \\ P(X \leq \alpha) + P(Y \leq \alpha) - P(X \leq \alpha, Y \leq \alpha)$$

Approach 2: Using the law of total probability: $$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha) = \\ 
P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha | X \leq Y)P(X \leq Y) + P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha|X > Y)P(X > Y) = \\
\frac{P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha, X \leq Y)}{P(X \leq Y)}P(X \leq Y) + \frac{P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha,X > Y)}{P(X > Y)}P(X > Y)=\\P(X \leq \alpha) + P(Y \leq \alpha)$$

I can't find any issues with the two approaches yet they yield different answers.

As a follow-up: I understand why $$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha | X \leq Y) \neq P(X \leq \alpha)$$ mathematically, but why isn't this true intuitively? What's wrong with the "logic", "If we condition on $X \leq Y$, then we can replace $min(X,Y)$ with $X$"?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about your follow-up? I'm almost certain that they're in fact equal.

Comment: $$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha, X \leq Y)=P(X \leq \alpha, X \leq Y)\ne P(X \leq \alpha)$$ $$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha, X> Y)=P(Y \leq \alpha, X > Y)\ne P(Y \leq \alpha)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$P(\min(X,Y) \leq \alpha) = 1 - P(\min(X,Y) > \alpha ) = 1 - P(\{X > \alpha\ , Y > \alpha\})$

where $P(\{X > \alpha\ , Y > \alpha\} ) = P(\{X > \alpha\}) \cdot P(\{ Y > \alpha\}) $

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the second approach.

You assumed (mistakenly) that $P(\min(X,Y)\leq \alpha, X\leq Y) = P(X\leq \alpha)$

This is false of course. For instance if $X,Y$ takes values in $[0,1]$ and are independent and if you take $\alpha=1$ then the right hand side becomes trivial (equals $1$) while the left hand side still have the condition that $X\leq Y$ which is satisfied with probability half.

Comment: Isn't it true that: $\{ \omega \in \Omega : min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \leq \alpha\} \cap \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega) \} = \{ \omega \in \Omega : min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \leq \alpha\} \cap \{ \omega \in \Omega : min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) = X(\omega) \} = \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq \alpha \}$

Comment: That is, $min(a, b) = a \iff a \leq b$

Comment: @fireyoni09 No it's not true (the first equality holds but the second doesn't). You are missing the condition that $X\leq Y$ this is not trivial! If you calculate the right hand side with the example I gave it turns out to be $\Omega$. But if you do so with the left hand side you get $\{w\in \Omega : \min(X(\omega),Y(\omega))=X(\omega)\}$